# Upload file element not interactable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

`Org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`

When I try to upload file but when I use action 'click', window to upload file is visible

```
@FindBy(id = "uniform-fileUpload")
WebElement uploadFile;
```

So when I try this method:

```
public void uploadFile(){
        uploadFile.click();
}
```

Everything is ok and window to select file is open so element is visible.

But when I try this:

```
        uploadFile.sendKeys("C:\\test.png");

    }
```

I have exeption:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

Page:

http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to send keystrokes to a `div`. You need to select on the `input` under the `div`, and then send the keystrokes to that instead.

```html
<div class="uploader" id="uniform-fileUpload">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" class="form-control">
    ...
</div>
```

Try id `fileUpload` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
@FindBy(id = "uniform-fileUpload")
WebElement uploadFile;
```

to

```
@FindBy(id = "fileUpload")
WebElement uploadFile;
```

Since this is the `input` element that needs to be the target for your file input.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when doing something like this in a generic methiod:

```cs
element.Clear(); // <-- OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException 
element.SendKeys(value);
```

Turns out, that you cannot use the `Clear()` function on an `<input type="file"/>` dialog.